# Get Created date from local path via asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help to get file created date from asp.net ascx (ex.)

This is load image from page

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = new Bitmap(flpContainer.FileContent);


// how to get image **created date** via uploading  from local machine (not uploading date)
```

I want try with FileInfo class, but for asp.net it not work to read a local file properities.

I have functional in web : User upload images from local file system to our application and I want take image created data in File system. I can create new column for created_date in DB, but  how I can take created Date image from FS (not created uploading date just created date in local machine via asp.net).

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is failing. What this line returns creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(fileName).ToString();

Comment: There is no created date for this file, it is not really a file as such, it is just the contents of a file stored in a stream. Certain types of file data my contain metadata such as exif data.

Comment: This will only work for file stored in the same web server, where request comes, else for end user ultimately file will be in there system, so there is no way to do `File.Exists(..)`, becasue file will be in client system and File.Exists will check in server location, as code runs on server.

Comment: If you are storing the file contents in a stream, I assume that you persist that stream somewhere (database?). In this case you need to create an extra column to capture the datetime that the stream gets persisted. You haven't disclosed more information about how you retrieve your stream, so not much we can do I'm afraid

Comment: @Chris - I have functional in web : User upload images from local file system to our application and I want take image created data in File system. I can create new column for created_date in DB, but  how I can take created Date image from FS (not created uploading date just created date in local machine via asp.net).

Comment: Please help for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eldar, that information is actually lost as it is not transmitted as part of the file upload. You can only get information about the file name. You could request your users to supply a create date as part of the upload or you could set it yourself as part of the upload process to `DateTime.Now`.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help